Is it true? If $S$ & $P$ are two linearly independent sets such that $P \cap \text{span(S)}=\emptyset$, then $P \cup S$ is linearly independent.

Let $S$ and $P$ are two linearly independent sets in a vector space $V$ such that $P \cap \text{span(S)}=\emptyset$. Then $P \cup S$ is linearly independent.

I was doing an exercise today where I used this result without proof. I thought it should be obvious, but I found myself running into a dead end when I attempted to prove it. Is the statement correct, and if it is, how to prove it?

Let $S = \{s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n\}$ and $P = \{p_1, p_2, \dots, p_m\}$ be two linearly independent sets, where $P \cap \text{span(S)} = \emptyset$.
Suppose there is a relation of the form $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\alpha_is_i+\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\beta_jp_j=\boldsymbol0$$where one of the $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m$ is nonzero.
Then one of $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_m$ must be nonzero, as otherwise $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ would be linearly dependent.
It follows that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^m\beta_jp_j\neq \boldsymbol0$, as otherwise $p_1, \dots, p_m$ would be linearly dependent.
On the other hand, we have $$x  = \sum_{j=1}^m\beta_jp_j=-\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_is_i\in\text{span(S)}.$$
Thus, $$\boldsymbol0 \neq x \in \text{span(P)} \cap \text{span(S)}$$

At this point, I'm stuck. How to go from $P \cap \text{span(S)}=\emptyset$ to $\text{span(P)} \cap \text{span(S)}=\{\boldsymbol0\}$?
Thank you!

This statement is wrong. A counterexample in $V:=\Bbb R^2$ is
$$P=\{(1,0),(0,1)\},\quad S=\{(1,1)\}.$$

Thank you very much!
